# Excel Pivot tables Summary from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have excel 2012 installed. I have a Excel which has two sheets. This excel is a summary of errors in each project till date.

Onesheet is a overall view of projects. This sheet has project_Id,Project_name,Total_errors

```
project_id||project_name||error
   3467   || project A  ||   5
   7890   || project B  ||   3
```

The second sheet has project_id,Project_name and location of each error.

```
project_id||project_name||error
  3467    || project A  ||com.testsample.projecta.service.controller
  3467    || project A  ||com.testsample.projecta.domains.user
  3467    || project A  ||com.testsample.projecta.domains.product
  3467    || project A  ||com.testsample.projecta.domains.test
  3467    || project A  ||com.testsample.projecta.domains.test2
  7890    || project B  ||com.testsample.projectb.domains.product
  7890    || project B  ||com.testsample.projectb.domains.users
  7890    || project B  ||com.testsample.projectb.domains.details
```

now i have been given a task of making a pivot table such that when i double click on the "error" in the first sheet i should get the the list of error from the second sheet. The result can be in another sheet or same sheet. Could some please let me know how i can go ahead with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- on a 3rd sheet to go insert, pivot table.
- select the range of values on sheet 2
- setup pivot table as in image. (by default pivot table have double click to drill in)
- image on bottom show results when you double click the pivot count of error value from the sheet 4 generated by the double click
  [image]